# How to use replace command while opening text file that has HTML tags?

Tags: python, html

I have a text file called `front.txt`:

```html
<a href="https://website/project_name.html" target="_blank">
<img src="https://website/project_name.webp" class="img img-responsive">
```

I am trying to develop a Python code that will ask user for "project_name" and replace that with their name.

This is what I have done:

```
filename = 'front.txt'

with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

your_project_name = input("Project Name? ")

for line in lines:
    line.replace("project_name", your_project_name)
    print(line.strip())
```

When I run my Python program, it is not able to replace `"project_name"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace does not operate inplace, so you have to assign the value to make it working.

```
filename = 'front.txt'

with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


your_project_name = input("Project Name? ")
    
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("project_name", your_project_name)
    print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. It would be my pleasure if you could explain me this line - "Replace does not operate inplace"

Comment: Perfect! Inplace means that the parameter is manipulated directly. So for instance you pass a dict  `a` to a function and change `a["a"] += 1` inside the function e.g. Strings in python are immutable so this won't work for strings, meaning that a new string is returned and the passed on not modified.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I understood it.